# Did the pre-lightbulb era rabbis have light bulbs

Tags: history

I remember hearing a story of how a rabbi had, prior to the discovery of electricity or creation of the light bulb (my memory of this story is vague), access to a light bulb which he used to learn throughout the night or something along those lines.
Has anyone heard of such a story?

Comment: כִּ֤י נֵ֣ר מִ֭צְוָה וְת֣וֹרָה א֑וֹר --  -- For the commandment is a lamp and the Torah is a light. [Proverbs 6:23]

Comment: Nope. There is a story of Maharshal learning by a candle that did not go out one night.

Comment: Even if they had access to a light bulb, how would they power it?

Comment: I remember hearing a fairy tale about the Gra having electricity.

Comment: @DoubleAA solar power or a dynamo. Or possibly the aish hatorah would be converted to an electrical current and power the bulb.  Potatoes though indigenous to America might also be employed as a power source.

Comment: I don't know if you're serious

Comment: @DoubleAA I don't either know if you're serious. Though my comment was serious.

Comment: @Shababnik only dynamo (faraday disc) is sensible out of those

Comment: @RabbiKaii there you have it!

Comment: @N.T. do you know where I can find that story?

Comment: @user6591 Do you know where I can find that story?

Comment: Shem Hagedolim by the Chida.

Comment: @Harel13 That's it! I remembered hearing this about a Rabbi Yechiel but couldn't find anything. I seem to recall something about a trapdoor too. Does that ring a bell for anyone?

Comment: @shmosel I added an answer giving the source of the story (Shalshelet Hakabbalah): https://judaism.stackexchange.com/questions/109296/source-for-electricity-in-the-times-of-the-talmud/137071#137071.

Answer (score 0):

I doubt that's true.  They used oil lamps.  Here is a story in the Talmud:

> If not for Ḥananya ben Ḥizkiya, the book of Ezekiel would have been suppressed because its contents... contradict matters of Torah. What did he do? They brought him three hundred jugs of oil up to his upper story and he sat there until he homiletically interpreted [all problematic verses in Ezekiel and resolved the contradictions]. [Shabbat 13b]

Comment: I'm not sure if this answers the question, but I 'm also not sure the question can be answered.

Comment: @יהושעק what makes you think so?

Comment: A single maaseh about a single rabbi in the Gamarra does not prove or disprove that no rabbi from the Tanaaim until Thomas Edison had a light bulb.@RabbiKaii, but what would?